# Delete rows of a pandas data frame having string values in python 3.4.1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have read a csv file with pandas `read_csv` having 8 columns. Each column may contain int/string/float values. But I want to remove those rows having string values and return a data frame with only numeric values in it. Attaching the csv sample.
I have tried to run this following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  
df = pd.read_csv('new200_with_errors.csv',dtype={'Geo_Level_1' : int,'Geo_Level_2' : int,'Geo_Level_3' : int,'Product_Level_1' : int,'Product_Level_2' : int,'Product_Level_3' : int,'Total_Sale' : float})
print(df)
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()
```

I am running with python 3.4.1.
Here is the sample csv.

```
Geo_L_1,Geo_L_2,Geo_L_3,Pro_L_1,Pro_L_2,Pro_L_3,Date,Sale
1, 2, 3, 129, 1, 5193316745, 1/1/2012, 9
1 ,2, 3, 129, 1, 5193316745, 1/1/2013,  
1, 2, 3, 129, 1, 5193316745, , 8
1, 2, 3, 129, NA, 5193316745, 1/10/2012, 10
1, 2, 3, 129, 1, 5193316745, 1/10/2013, 4
1, 2, 3, ghj, 1, 5193316745, 1/10/2014, 6
1, 2, 3, 129, 1, 5193316745, 1/11/2012, 4
1, 2, 3, 129, 1, ghgj, 1/11/2013, 2
1, 2, 3, 129, 1, 5193316745, 1/11/2014, 6
1, 2, 3, 129, 1, 5193316745, 1/12/2012, ghgj
1, 2, 3, 129, 1, 5193316745, 1/12/2013, 5
```

Comment: I count only 5 columns. Where are Geo_Level_1..3 ?

Comment: You'll have to post raw data of your complete df, you either have to clean up the csv before or after reading it into pandas

Comment: the sample data has these errors in the aforesaid columns that is why i had given but the sample data consists of all the 8 columns. @fredtantini

Comment: i have just edited the main sample csv file i.e complete df. @EdChum

Comment: What do you want to do with the empty date row?

Comment: We have to delete those rows which have blank/NA/0/string values. @EdChum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way I would approach this is to try to convert the columns to an int using a user function with a `Try`/`Catch` to handle the situation where the value cannot be coerced into an Int, these get set to `NaN` values. Drop the row where you have an empty value, for some reason it actually has a length of 1 when I tested this with your data, it may work for you using len 0.

```
In [42]:
# simple function to try to convert the type, returns NaN if the value cannot be coerced
def func(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return NaN
# assign multiple columns 
df['Pro_L_1'], df['Pro_L_3'], df['Sale'] = df['Pro_L_1'].apply(func), df['Pro_L_3'].apply(func), df['Sale'].apply(func)
# drop the 'empty' date row, take a copy() so we don't get a warning
df = df.loc[df['Date'].str.len() > 1].copy()
# convert the string to a datetime, if we didn't drop the row it would set the empty row to today's date
df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# now convert all the dtypes that are numeric to a numeric dtype
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
# check the dtypes
df.dtypes

Out[42]:
Geo_L_1             int64
Geo_L_2             int64
Geo_L_3             int64
Pro_L_1           float64
Pro_L_2           float64
Pro_L_3           float64
Date       datetime64[ns]
Sale              float64
dtype: object
In [43]:
# display the current situation
df
Out[43]:
    Geo_L_1  Geo_L_2  Geo_L_3  Pro_L_1  Pro_L_2     Pro_L_3       Date  Sale
0         1        2        3      129        1  5193316745 2012-01-01     9
1         1        2        3      129        1  5193316745 2013-01-01   NaN
3         1        2        3      129      NaN  5193316745 2012-01-10    10
4         1        2        3      129        1  5193316745 2013-01-10     4
5         1        2        3      NaN        1  5193316745 2014-01-10     6
6         1        2        3      129        1  5193316745 2012-01-11     4
7         1        2        3      129        1         NaN 2013-01-11     2
8         1        2        3      129        1  5193316745 2014-01-11     6
9         1        2        3      129        1  5193316745 2012-01-12   NaN
10        1        2        3      129        1  5193316745 2013-01-12     5
In [44]:
# drop the rows
df.dropna()
Out[44]:
    Geo_L_1  Geo_L_2  Geo_L_3  Pro_L_1  Pro_L_2     Pro_L_3       Date  Sale
0         1        2        3      129        1  5193316745 2012-01-01     9
4         1        2        3      129        1  5193316745 2013-01-10     4
6         1        2        3      129        1  5193316745 2012-01-11     4
8         1        2        3      129        1  5193316745 2014-01-11     6
10        1        2        3      129        1  5193316745 2013-01-12     5
```

For the last line assign it so `df = df.dropna()`